# How to round datetime to nearest time of day, preferably vectorized?

Tags: r, datetime, rounding, posixct

Say I have a POSIXct vector like

```
timestamps = seq(as.POSIXct("2021-01-23"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-24"), length.out = 6)
```

I would like to round these times up to the nearest hour of the day in a vector:

```
hours_of_day = c(6, 14, 20)
```

i.e., the following result:

```
           timestamps              result
1 2021-01-23 00:00:00 2021-01-23 02:00:00
2 2021-01-23 04:48:00 2021-01-23 14:00:00
3 2021-01-23 09:36:00 2021-01-23 14:00:00
4 2021-01-23 14:24:00 2021-01-23 20:00:00
5 2021-01-23 19:12:00 2021-01-23 20:00:00
6 2021-01-24 00:00:00 2021-01-24 02:00:00
```

Is there a vectorized solution to this (or otherwise fast)? I have a few million timestamps and need to apply it for several `hours_of_day`.

One way to simplify this problem is to (1) find the next `hours_of_day` for each `lubridate::hour(timestamps)` and then (2) `result = lubridate::floor_date(timestamps) + next_hour_of_day * 3600`. But how to do step 1 vectorized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `as.POSIXlt`, which allows you to extract hours and minutes, and calculate decimal hours. In an `lapply`/`sapply` combination first look up where these are less than the hours of the day vector, and choose the maximum hour using `which.max`. Now create new date-time using `ISOdate` and add one day `ifelse` date-time is smaller than original time.

```
timestamps <- as.POSIXlt(timestamps)

h <- hours_of_day[sapply(lapply(with(timestamps, hour + min/60 + sec/3600), 
                                `<=`, hours_of_day), which.max)]
r <- with(timestamps, ISOdate(1900 + year, mon + 1, mday, h,
                              tz=attr(timestamps, "tzone")[[1]]))
r[r < timestamps] <- r[r < timestamps] + 86400
```

#### Result

```
r
# [1] "2021-01-23 06:00:00 CET" "2021-01-23 06:00:00 CET"
# [3] "2021-01-23 14:00:00 CET" "2021-01-23 20:00:00 CET"
# [5] "2021-01-23 20:00:00 CET" "2021-01-24 06:00:00 CET"
# [7] "2021-01-25 06:00:00 CET" "2021-01-27 20:00:00 CET"

data.frame(timestamps, r)
#            timestamps                   r
# 1 2021-01-23 00:00:00 2021-01-23 06:00:00
# 2 2021-01-23 04:48:00 2021-01-23 06:00:00
# 3 2021-01-23 09:36:00 2021-01-23 14:00:00
# 4 2021-01-23 14:24:00 2021-01-23 20:00:00
# 5 2021-01-23 19:12:00 2021-01-23 20:00:00
# 6 2021-01-24 00:00:00 2021-01-24 06:00:00
# 7 2021-01-24 23:59:00 2021-01-25 06:00:00
# 8 2021-01-27 20:00:00 2021-01-27 20:00:00
```

*Note:* I've added `"2021-01-24 23:59:00 CET"` to `timestamps` to demonstrate the date change.

---

#### Benchmark

Tested on a length 1.4e6 vector.

```
# Unit: seconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#      POSIX() 32.96197 33.06495 33.32104 33.16793 33.50057 33.83321     3  a 
#  lubridate() 47.36412 47.57762 47.75280 47.79113 47.94715 48.10316     3   b
```

---

*Data:*

```
timestamps <- structure(c(1611356400, 1611373680, 1611390960, 1611408240, 1611425520, 
1611442800, 1611529140, 1611774000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
))
hours_of_day <- c(6, 14, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks, but these results are incorrect. `timestamps[2]` is rounded 
*down*.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv Thanks, updated code! Why is `timestamps[4]` of the other solution, which is rounded down, not incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I accepted your answer. It takes ~ 7 secs for 1.4 mio POSIXct timestamps on my laptop.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv Welcome! I definitely need to buy a new laptop if your 7 sec is true.

Comment: I just discovered two issues with your solution. (1) It rounds up `POSIXct("2021-01-27 20:00")`, and (2) `ISOdate` defaults to `tz = "GMT"` witch causes issues if `timestamps` are in a different time zone. I posted a new answer fixing these and generalizing to a `floor` function too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JonasLindeløv 1. We just have to use decimal hours and change `<` to `<=` to avoid the rounding up (edit). 2. Where do timestamps come from? Can `tz=` information be found in original data, or are they created on your system in your code? Your `timestamps` don't include that information.

Comment: Ah, that's a better elegant solution. And you could add ` + sec/3600` as well to go all the way. `timestamps` can have several different time zones, though often UTC. It seems that because `tz(timestamps)` is "" in this case, it defaults to the system tz? Works either way if `ISOdate(..., tz = tz(timestamps))`.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv Added sec! `lubridate::tz` fetches just `attr(timestamps, "tzone")[[1]]`, should work when we add that to `ISOdate` (edit).

Comment: Thanks, all good now! Feel free to copy my floor-answer in here, and I'll delete it. Otherwise, I'll just let it be.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the `hour` component, use `cut` to bin it, and assign the binned hours back to the original:

```
hours_of_day = c(2, 14, 20)

library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)  ## just for the pipe
new_hours = timestamps %>% 
  hour %>% 
  cut(breaks = c(0, hours_of_day), labels = hours_of_day, include.lowest = TRUE) %>% 
  as.character() %>%
  as.integer()

result = floor_date(timestamps, "hour")
hour(result) = new_hours

result
# [1] "2021-01-23 02:00:00 EST" "2021-01-23 14:00:00 EST" "2021-01-23 14:00:00 EST"
# [4] "2021-01-23 14:00:00 EST" "2021-01-23 20:00:00 EST" "2021-01-24 02:00:00 EST"
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. Running `bench::mark()`, I find that it takes ~ 2 secs for 1.4 mio. rows and three cutpoints on a mediocre laptop.

Comment: You could probably cut down the time by not using `cut` - for only 3 possibilities a nested `ifelse` (or better, `if_else` or `case_when` from `dplyr`) would be a bit faster than `cut` by avoiding the class conversions.

Comment: Rounds down `timestamps[4]` and doesn't work with `"2021-01-24 23:59:00"`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the approach by @jay.sf, I made a function for floor as well while adding support for `NA` values.

```r
floor_date_to = function(timestamps, hours_of_day) {

  # Handle NA with a temporary filler so code below doesn't break
  na_timestamps = is.na(timestamps)
  timestamps[na_timestamps] = as.POSIXct("9999-12-31")  

  # Proceed as usual
  timestamps = as.POSIXlt(timestamps)
  hours_of_day = rev(hours_of_day)  # floor-specific: because which.max returns the first index by default
  nearest_hour = hours_of_day[sapply(lapply(with(timestamps, hour + min/60 + sec/3600), `<`, hours_of_day), function(x) which.max(-x))]  # floor-specific: negative which.max()
  rounded = with(timestamps, ISOdate(1900 + year, mon + 1, mday, nearest_hour, tz = attr(timestamps, "tzone")[1]))
  rounded[rounded > timestamps] = rounded[rounded > timestamps] - 86400  # floor: use minus
  return(rounded)
  timestamps[na_timestamps] = NA  # Overwrite with NA again
}
```